# SQL Server: Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, latitude-longitude

I have the following `SELECT` statement to calculate `RADIANS` and `COS`.

```
SELECT COS(RADIANS(latitude)) as Lat 
FROM tbl_geometry;
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

My attempts:

**Attempt #1**:

```
select Cos(convert(float, (Radians(convert(float, latitude))))) as Lat 
from tbl_geometry;
```

**Attempt #2**.

```
select Cos(Radians(convert(float, latitude))) as Lat 
from tbl_geometry;
```

Both attempts result in the same error.

**Note**: column `Latitude` is of type `varchar`.

Comment: Seems like your latitude column contains invalid float data.

Comment: @jarlh, Yes you'r right! I have some invalid data in that column, and that is because it is of type `varchar` which containse `NULL, abc,` etc. How to overcome with this?

Comment: The best way to "overcome" this is to stop using the varchar datatype when you need float information. And if NULL is causing you problems you should make the column not nullable. If you build your data structures correctly, retrieving the information back out is pretty painless.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! So ***WHY ON EARTH*** are you storing your latitude - which is **clearly** a numerical value - as a `varchar` ?!?!?!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `try_convert()` to find the invalid data:

```
select latitude
from tbl_geometry
where try_convert(float, latitude) is null;
```

`try_convert()` is available in SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: I am using SSMS 2012 but still unable to find that built-in function. Your script gives me `'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name`.

Comment: @MAK The SSMS version is not automatically the same as your DBMS version (SQL *Server*). Try running `PRINT @@version` to see the SQL *Server* version.

Comment: Do you have compability level set for that database? What does `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases where name = 'your database'`

Comment: @HoneyBadger, The compatibility level is 100.

Comment: @PeterB, Exactly! It's not same. It's 2008 R2 (SP1). So how to solve this? :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT      CASE
                WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', latitude) > 0 THEN 0
                ELSE Cos(Radians(convert(float,latitude)))
            end as latitude          
FROM        tbl_geometry
```

You can use the `THEN` to fill the attribute with `null` or other values if non-convertable values are encountered. Or you can use the `PATINDEX` in the `WHERE` if you want to skip those rows all together. (You may have to play around with the `patindex`, I don't usually use `floats`, so I'm not sure what is and isn't allowed. You may want to include decimal points, for example.)